# How can I manage which apps use a VPN and which do not?

Tags: networking, vpn, citrix, cyberghost

Yes, this is another "how do I use Cisco Anyconnect with a VPN"-style question, but it's not quite the same as the answers I found so far.  Most of those seem to be about managing its routing table on an enterprise network and that's sort of the opposite of what I'm doing.

I use CyberGhost as a VPN for anonymity at home when I use TOR and access some of my websites and accounts.  Unfortunately, both my office PC remote access and one of my online gaming accounts require that I *not* use a VPN as part of their policies.  Using CyberGhost, how can I protect my personal-use traffic with the VPN while running other applications such as Citrix Receiver and gaming applications from my normal IP address?

Answer (score 1):

It's resource intensive, but if possible, the easiest thing to do for desktop environments is use virtual machines, VMWare, VirtualBOX, QEMU, etc.  Install the VPN software needed inside the VM, and software you want to work off that VPN, use outside of the VM.

For example, make a VM for Tor use, and a VM for work VPN use.